# Finding which color is the closest to the given RGB values in C

Tags: c, arrays, colors, rgb

Here is a website that contains 20 colors that are the most simple and distinct: http://sashat.me/2017/01/11/list-of-20-simple-distinct-colors/

I am making a program that detects colors and gives them a name.

The problem is that I need a function that would:

- Take in 3 parameters, R, G, and B.
- Determine which of the 20 is this color the closest when the function is given the RGB.

Here are some examples of the ideal function:

```
[127,2,1] -> Outputs Maroon
[245,7,6] -> Outputs Red
[7,235,0] -> Outputs Green
```

Any help on how to make something like this would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

Comment: I'm no expert but maybe take the closest value to sum of differences or sum of square of differences?

Comment: There's no definite answer - attempts to create a perceptually uniform colour space land you in deep waters very quickly. But 5 x difference in red, 9 x difference in green and 2 x difference in blue is a good start.

Comment: @HansPassant I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered my own question in order to help future viewers.

Using the color difference formula found on the wikipedia and shown in the comments, this function will take in 3 parameters and return the closest color.

```
const int distinctRGB[22][3] = {{255, 255, 255},{0,0,0},{128,0,0},{255,0,0},{255, 200, 220},{170, 110, 40},{255, 150, 0},{255, 215, 180},{128, 128, 0},{255, 235, 0},{255, 250, 200},{190, 255, 0},{0, 190, 0},{170, 255, 195},{0, 0, 128},{100, 255, 255},{0, 0, 128},{67, 133, 255},{130, 0, 150},{230, 190, 255},{255, 0, 255},{128, 128, 128}};
const String distinctColors[22] = {"white","black","maroon","red","pink","brown","orange","coral","olive","yellow","beige","lime","green","mint","teal","cyan","navy","blue","purple","lavender","magenta","grey"};
String closestColor(int r,int g,int b) {
  String colorReturn = "NA";
  int biggestDifference = 1000;
  for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
    if (sqrt(pow(r - distinctRGB[i][0],2) + pow(g - distinctRGB[i][1],2) + pow(b - distinctRGB[i][2],2)) < biggestDifference) {
      colorReturn = distinctColors[i];
      biggestDifference = sqrt(pow(r - distinctRGB[i][0],2) + pow(g - distinctRGB[i][1],2) + pow(b - distinctRGB[i][2],2));
    }
  }
  return colorReturn;
}
```

This function uses `Math.h` in order to do the formula with less typing.

Comment: Very helpful! Could you explain how you come to`int biggestDifference = 1000;`? I don't understand where the value of 1000 comes from and why. Thanks!

Comment: @Systembolaget 1000 is bigger than 255*3, so I just chose some number bigger than 765 to be the initial value

Comment: Alright, thanks; I was wondering about that "magic number" that seemed to come from nowhere. I am using a colour sensor that outputs ~9000 as the maximum value for r, g and b each, so I should use 9000*3.